# PHP OOP: Can a variable be seen in a function without passing it as a param?

Tags: php

I was wondering if anyone could help me understand this particular aspect of OO PHP as it has caught me out a few times now.

I have specified a var at the top of my file like so

```
$route = explode('/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
// Shorthand
$r1=$route[0]; $r2=$route[1]; $r3=$route[2];
```

I am then tring to use $r1 etc inside a function written just below the above code.

```
function edit($id)
   {
            $_SESSION['path'] = $r1 . "/" . $r2 . "/" . $r3;
            require 'app/controller/edit.php';
            new Controller($id);
   }
```

The $r1,$r2, $r3 vars cannot be seen for some reason inside this function.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: r1 in C:\wamp\www\options.ex\public_html\app\options.php on line 77
```

If I were to pass the $r vars to the function, I'd image there would be no problem, but since they are declared globally I was wondering why they were not visible without doing this as their scope presumably is global?

Thanks.

EDIT - full code.

```
<?php

require_once 'load.php';


// Clean and prepare query string
$route = explode('/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    // Trim outer exmpty parameters caused by leading/trailing slash
    if($route[count($route)-1]=='') unset($route[count($route)-1]);
    if($route[0]=='') unset($route[0]);
    $route = array_values($route);
    // If any parameters are undefined, set them to ''
    if(!isset($route[0])) { $route[0]=''; $route[1]=''; $route[2]='';  }
    elseif(!isset($route[1])) { $route[1]=''; $route[2]='';  }
    elseif(!isset($route[2])) { $route[2]='';  }
// Shorthand
$r1=$route[0]; $r2=$route[1]; $r3=$route[2];

// Choose route, else default to dash
if($r1=='dashboard' && $r2=='' && $r3=='')          dashboard();
elseif($r1=='staff' && $r2=='add' && $r3=='')       add_staff();
elseif($r1=='staff' && $r2=='edit' && $r3!='')      edit_staff($r3);

else header("location: http://local.options.ex/dashboard");



// Dashboard: Main entry point after login.
function dashboard()
   {
            require 'app/controller/dashboard/dashboard.php';
            new Controller();

   }

// Staff related interfaces ----------------------------------------------------
function add_staff()
   {
            require 'app/controller/staff/add_staff.php';
            new Controller();
   }

// ----------------------------------------
function edit_staff($staff_id)
   {
            $_SESSION['path'] = $r1 . "/" . $r2 . "/" . $r3;
            require 'app/controller/staff/edit_staff.php';
            new Controller($staff_id);
   }

// ----------------------------------------
```

Just to clear up, the $r* variables are not used again beyond here, hence the convenient use of storing in session.

Comment: I don't see any global declaration on the $r1,$r2 and $r3. Something is missing?

Comment: I removed the OOP tag, because this is not related to OOP. In fact, the code looks procedural to me. Your issue itself is about variable scope and sufficiently explained in the PHP Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble with variable scope in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962332/trouble-with-variable-scope-in-php)

Comment: *(related)* http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=variable+scope+php

Answer (score 1):

That's not OOP - in OOP you'd declare a class, make r1, r2 and r3 its properties, and then they would be available in every method of the class. See a little tutorial about classes [here](http://www.simplyian.com/2010/04/17/how-to-add-parameters-to-your-php-class-constructor-tutorial/).

Using global variables is a bad idea.

EDIT

Here's a sample code, like Sohnee asked:

```
Class Route {
    var $r1;
    var $r2;
    var $r3;

    function __construct($url)
    {
        $route = explode('/', $url);
        // Shorthand
        $this->r1=$route[0]; $this->r2=$route[1]; $this->r3=$route[2];
    }

    function test()
    {
            $path = $this->r1 . "/" . $this->r2 . "/" . $this->r3;
            echo $path;
    }

}

$a = new Route('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/');
$a->test();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Global](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) variables can be accessed within functions, if you declare them as global (which creates a local [reference to the global](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.references)). However, [globals are bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

If the variable definition happens in "app/controller/edit.php", then the problem is as the warning tells you: the variables aren't defined yet. You use them on one line, but don't include the file that defines them until the next, so they aren't yet defined. It's the same as if the function were:

```
function edit($id) {
    $_SESSION['path'] = $r1 . "/" . $r2 . "/" . $r3;
    $route = explode('/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    // Shorthand
    $r1=$route[0]; $r2=$route[1]; $r3=$route[2];
    ...
}
```

I recommend against the obvious fix: moving the require to before the line that uses the variables, as this shares one of the big problems with globals: the variables seemingly magically spring into existence, with no indication of how or where, making it harder to understand the function (and the rest of the code) simply by reading the function. It's a form of [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_science%29).

Executing code by including files can occasionally be a useful trick, but it also often causes problems (as this question demonstrates). Generally, include files should only define things. For an OO approach, take whatever tasks are being performed by the included file and figure out what jobs the code is trying to achieve overall. Then, assign each task to the class that has the (single) responsibility of achieving each overall job. In this case, the specific task is breaking up a request into a route, and the overall job is dispatching a request to a controller. There should then be a dispatcher class that dispatches a request to the appropriate controller, with a method that parses the route. The method (which might be private or protected and called from the constructor) could store the route in instance variables for time-efficiency.

```
class RouteDispatcher {
    protected $route;

    function __construct() {
        $this->_parseRoute();
        ...
    }

    function dispatch() {
        ...
    }

    protected function _parseRoute() {
        $this->route = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    }

    ...
}
```

The entry point (the script that is first called to handle each request) would instantiate a `RequestDispatcher`, set any appropriate properties or call any necessary methods, then call `RequestDispatcher::dispatch`, which would create the appropriate controller and hand off control to its request handler.

In the general case, a good design can be trickier than this because your goal as a designer in creating classes that have a [single responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) is to cut down on the need to change them. If a class has only one responsibility, then the class will need to be changed only if the requirements for that responsibility change.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking i'd like to avoid Globals. It was really just a question of: can a function only access the variables that are passed to it and nothing outside?

Comment: @GHarping: what scope are the variables? The [code sample](http://sscce.org/) is incomplete. Without that information, it's impossible to know what you're dealing with at.

Comment: Well, the route variables and their shorthands, r1 etc, only are required as far as whats written in the sample and no further - so up to the function. That why I'm keen not to declare them global, however there will be many differently named versions of the same function so I suppose, for the sake of my OCD, I'd rather not pass the variables everytime to each different function if that were possible?

Comment: @GHarping: that doesn't answer my question. Please edit your question, making the code sample complete and demonstrating the scope of the variables. As it stands, it's not possible to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help. That essentially is it as far as the code is concerned for those variables. As you can see the funcitons load the controller classes which loads then model ... etc and so on and its gets rather convoluted from that point so editing the sample to contain all of that all may be overkill. As far as the variables listed though they end there...

Comment: @GHarping: You don't need to include everything, just enough to reproduce the issue, as the "code sample" link in my first comment to this answer explains. I don't like to have to repeat myself. If the lines that define the variables occur in "app/controller/edit.php", you should state this explicitly. Otherwise, the problem is underspecified. The single most essential skill in development is being able to unambiguously and completely describe a problem.

Comment: @GHarping: no, don't post the full code. You're making me repeat myself. Repeatedly. Read the link; post just enough to reproduce the issue. If the variables are being defined in "app/controller/edit.php", say so in the question. This is then enough to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I appreciate your help but this isn't something i'm stuck on, just curious as to why it was the case that the $r variables were not visible in the function - generally a question on scope in PHP. I think I stated fairly clearly that the $r vars are no longer used beyond what was supplied in the sample - "r1 etc, only are required as far as whats written ...

Comment: ... in the sample and no further - so up to the function" - AND - "As far as the variables listed though they end there" AND - "That essentially is it as far as the code is concerned for those variables" AND "As far as the variables listed though they end there".... Hence there was no need to reproduce further that waht was there anyway. If it wasn't clear they are no longer used, then my apologies. Thank you very much for your help in any case.

Comment: @GHarping: why aren't you answering my question? **Are the `$route` &c. variables being defined in "app/controller/edit.php"?** If so, answer my request for clarification by editing this piece of information into your question. All you need to do is change "I have specified a var at the top of my file like so" to something like "I have defined the following variables at the top of the file 'app/controller/edit.php'". Moreover, my answer addresses this possibility and explains why it generates an "Undefined variable" notice. You keep bringing up irrelevancies.

Comment: I am using specified and defined interchangabley. Since there is no specific term 'specified' like there is 'defined' which has an clear meaning, it could be safe to assume from the context that my lazy use of language referrs to define. It's not a deep, intricate problem like you may think, just something I was wondering about. Cheers.

Comment: @GHarping: again, irrelevant. It doesn't matter whether you write "specified" or "defined"; the important part is the answer to question I keep asking you and which you keep failing to provide: ***are the variables defined in "app/controller/edit.php"***? What don't you understand about my question? Why won't you answer it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use global variables inside a function, you have to do it via the following way

```
$route = explode('/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
// Shorthand
$r1=$route[0]; $r2=$route[1]; $r3=$route[2];
// ...  
function edit($id)
{
    global $r1, $r2, $r3;  // after this the variables are available in function scope

}
```

Another option is to use global array $GLOBALS. Using this array a global variable can be accessed from any scope like this:

```
if ($GLOBALS["r1"] == "some value")
{ 
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ADD this inside the function.

global $r1, $r2, $r3;

This tells the function to use the variables from the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

global variables can be seen inside a method using `$GLOBALS`

```
$GLOBALS — References all variables available in global scope
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

```
<?php

$baz = 'foo';

clas Bar {

    public function __construct() {
        echo $GLOBALS['baz'];
    }
}
```

or inside a function declaring variables global

```
function bar() {
    global $baz;
    echo $baz
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If $r1, $r2, and $r3 are defined outside any class or function definition, you can use the global keyword to access them, or directly call them from the $GLOBALS array. e.x.:

```
function edit($id){
  global $r1, $r2, $r3; //Rest of the function below this
```

or

```
$_SESSION['path'] = $GLOBALS['r1'].'/' //... etc.
```